# How can I manually add a root node in XGBoost tree(s)?

Tags: xgboost

I have a binary feature `{0, 1}` and only when its value is `1`, I would like my XGBoost model to "evaluate" a set of trees. The goal is to save on prediction time by not evaluating a set of trees when the binary feature's value is `0`.

So I was thinking if this feature is the root node of those trees, with rest of the tree being the subtree on the value of `1` of this feature, I may achieve my goal.

Is it possible to tweak XGBoost model in such a way?

Answer (score 2):

It would be best to add that as control logic outside of the model.

If you were using Python, it would be something like:

```py
from xgboost import XGBClassifier

model = XGBClassifier()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

if feature == 1:
    y = model.predict(X)
else feature == 0:
    print("No prediciton made.")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Brian Spiering. This would be my last resort if the model itself can't support it. I made my preference for the model itself to support it because our workplace's software doesn't support "ensembling" like in your answer.